# Where are document options in altium 2020

Tags: altium, parameters

I switched to altium 2020 and I can't find the document options dialog that was previously available  in "design / document options". I want to set parameters like in the screenshot (altium 2017).
How should I do?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a question for Altium support/hotline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the document you want to see the options for. Open the Properties Panel and go to Parameters.

[image]